# Bug or feature? Insert does not insert at the current point position in the buffer

Tags: insert

Below two screenshots:

---

The first one before executing `eval-buffer` on the *scratch* buffer:

[image]

---

The second one after executing 'eval-buffer`:

[image]

---

As you can see above the commands have inserted the text directly into the text after the code of the commands and not at the location of the current point (i.e. cursor).

Is something wrong with my expectation that if I evaluate the buffer content the inserts should happen at the position of the point placed one line below the code (as shown in the first image)?

Comment: The code is working as designed.  In writing Lisp code, one navigates to a desired location with `goto-char` and then `insert`; and, to preserve point and go elsewhere temporarily, one uses `save-excursion` (which wraps around the applicable code) followed by `goto-char` and then `insert`.

Comment: Sorry ... don't understand what you are trying to say. How should I modify the code so that it inserts at position of point at the time of starting evaluation of the code?

Comment: (`(let ((pt (point))) (goto-char pt) (insert (format "hello-world | pt (%s)" pt)))` or `(let ((pt (point))) (save-excursion (goto-char pt) (insert (format "hello-world | pt (%s)" pt))))`  See also commonly used points of reference such as `point-min` and `point-max`.

Comment: Sorry again ... I have trouble to make the code you provided work on the code I have. You introduce in your code additional complexity using format. The point-min and point-max are the start and end of butter if I remember it right. What I need is the current position and a way to tell insert to insert there. You 'hide' the point of insertion within the format. Is there no way to insert at desired position without using format?

Comment: `format` was used in the example to help demonstrate where point is at the time the code is executed.  Point is determined at the outset and let-bound to `pt`.  You can eliminate the `format` statement and change it to any string desired, such as "hello-world".  `save excursion` would be used for a more complex situation when one desires to move elsewhere in the buffer or when point will be changing due to the code executed, and then automatically return to the original location.

Comment: Complexity is also introduced with let which makes the point a local symbol. Would `(setq pt 'point)` do the same? Or would `(goto-char '(point))` be already ok ? Would you be so kind to provide code working on my example and inserting in the last line of code one entry after another? Then I can study the code and find out why it does what it does having a better starting point.

Comment: The problem with using `point` in conjunction with your example is that it changes when calling  `M-x eval-buffer`; i.e., the buffer is evaluated from top to bottom.  `setq` would create a global variable that persists after the code is evaluated, unless that variable had been let-bound previously within the snippet. I hesitate to use the code in the example, because the use-case is unclear and the target buffer is the buffer containing the code that is to be evaluated (which is an unusual use-case). Offhand, I cannot think of an example that does not introduce some level of complexity ...

Comment: `eval-buffer` does more or less the equivalent of a `save-excursion` with a body of: go to the beginning of buffer and loop doing `forward-sexp` and `eval-last-sexp` until it gets to the end of the buffer. That's a simplfied first approximation of what it does, but it's close enough.

Comment: The use-case is easy explained. You run the code and get the current state in the last line. You run it again later and see in the added line compared to the previous one what has changes since last run. And in the process you have documented the runs (adding time/date).

Comment: Put the code in a `progn` and evaluate it with `C-j` in the `*scratch*` buffer. That will add a newline and put the output on the next line.

Comment: @NickD : please check out my answer if there are any problems with the explanation I have provided about how Emacs works while evaluating code in a buffer. By the way: would it be the same if the code would be run from a file and writing to the file? Would elisp move the file pointer of an for reading and writing opened file? So that placing the file pointer to the end of the file would be changed after each executed statement?

Comment: It depends on how you evaluate it. The description in the answer looks OK to me, but as I said, it is a first approximation of what it really does (it goes into a read-eval loop taking its input from the buffer). Part of the confusion is that you are using `insert` which is almost always done interactively: it inserts at `point` so almost by definition, the `point` was being changed during the evaluations. The whole thing was inside a `save-excursion` however, so afterwards you are at the same `point` as you were before.

Comment: But most of the time, `eval-buffer` is used to (re-)evaluate function definitions, so it makes not difference that `point` went on a journey behind your back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Is there something wrong with my expectation that if I evaluate the buffer content the inserts should happen at the position of the point placed one line below the code (as shown in the first image)?*

The problem with your expectation is that Emacs works not the way you assume it should work. The current position of the point is changed already at the start of the evaluation of the buffer to the buffer start. Then the evaluation uses the point and changes its current position statement after statement it evaluates. From this perspective the inserts happen at the right position: the position after the just evaluated statement where the evaluation moved the current point to.

In order to achieve the effect you expect you can use the above knowledge and wrap all the statements into one. And knowing that the current position will be the char directly after the last bracket of the statement you need to insert a newline in order to get the output in the next line. See the code below after it was evaluated:

```
(progn
(insert "\n")
(insert "  " (locate-library "font-lock")) ;; /usr/local/share/emacs/29.0.60/lisp/font-lock.elc
(insert "  " (locate-library "linum"    )) ;; /usr/local/share/emacs/29.0.60/lisp/obsolete/linum.elc
)
  /usr/local/share/emacs/29.0.60/lisp/font-lock.elc  /usr/local/share/emacs/29.0.60/lisp/obsolete/linum.elc
```

Notice that the evaluation restores the position of the point it has been moving around during its work to the original position in the text. If it was placed in part without insertions to exactly the same position. And if it was placed behind the part with insertions moved further by the total length/size of the insertions.